# Concatenate/Join Template Elements with a "+"

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Is there a way to concatenate template elements? I have this template, which is a loop, but I can't figure out how I can concatenate/join multiple items. If I place the `+` inside the `<kbd>` tag, I get an extra `+` at the end and it is within the kbd tag (which I would like outside of the tag).

```html
<template>
  <kbd v-for="(v, i) in item" :key="i">{{ v }}</kbd>
</template>
```

The data I am using looks something like this (I am actually using a store):

```js
data: () {
  return {
    item: [ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]
  }
}
```

The result I am looking for is:

```html
<kbd>a</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy enough. Conditional rendering based on index. Something similar to this should work:

```html
<template v-for="(v, i) in item">
  {{i > 0 ? ' + ' : ''}}<kbd :key="i">{{ v }}</kbd>
</template>
```

Comment: Awesome! Still new to vue, so didn't think of this.

Comment: Small aside: don't use an array index for a `:key`. It's equivalent to not having any `:key` at all. Better to either omit it or modify your data structure to include unique IDs for each element.

Comment: No problem! There's a lot to learn. Luckily the documentation isn't particularly heavy. I highly recommend taking a deep dive into it because there are a lot of things that are useful in there.