# How to "join" elements in Vue with a separator?

Tags: vue.js

In Python, there is a simple way to chain elements with a separator which is only added between the "inner" elements:

```
>>> print(" → ".join(['hello', 'world', 'bonjour']))
hello → world → bonjour
```

I am wondering whether there is a simple way to do the same in Vue.js. I was thinking about using `<v-for>` for that, but I do not think I can influence the way the iteration is built:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    boxes: [1, 2, 3]
  },
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="box in boxes" class="box">hello</div>
</div>
```

**Is there a way to add a separator (→) between the first and second, and the second and third box?**

Comment: Like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58885611

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `box` class, you can use javascript `split` and `join` function

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    boxes: ['hello', 'world', 'bonjour']
  },
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="box in boxes.join(' →').split(' ')" class="">{{box}}</div>
</div>
```

In your existing code

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    boxes: [1, 2, 3]
  },
})
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  background-color: red;
  width: 60px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div v-for="box,index in boxes" class="">
      <span class="box">Hello</span><span v-if="index<boxes.length-1">=></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is clever, thank you. I did not think to conditionally show the →, depending on the index in the iteration.

Answer (score -1):

This is not a Vue specific problem, you can use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to insert a separator between array items.

In your use case, you may create a computed property like this

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    boxes: [1, 2, 3]
  },
  computed: {
    // returns '1→2→3'
    boxesWithSeparator() {
      return this.boxes.join('→')
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: It is a specific Vue problem: I am not trying to join the content of an Array but to display boxes interconnected by a separator. The boxes are dynamically managed by Vue (when the content of `boxes` change, the display does this as well)